# Remove duplicate print in python code

Tags: python

How can I remove duplicate print statement issue_assign and go to the nextline. The output should be like this.

**Currently My print output looks like this:**

> **Assign**
>
> Key, Summary , Reporter , Name , Resolution , Createdate , UpdateDate , Due , Team
>
> **Assign**
>
> Key, Summary , Reporter , Name , Resolution , Createdate , UpdateDate , Due , Team
>
> ...

**I want the output to be like this, without any duplicate.**

> **Assign**
>
> Key, Summary , Reporter , Name , Resolution , Createdate , UpdateDate , Due ,Team
>
> Key, Summary , Reporter , Name , Resolution , Createdate , UpdateDate , Due , 
>   Team
>
> ...

My code looks like this

```
def assigne(username):
    responses = fetch(server + Ticket_Week + ' and assignee='+ username)

    duplicate = []
    object = {}
    for issue in responses['issues']:
        issue_fields = issue['fields']
        issue_status = issue_fields['status']
        issue_reporter = issue_fields['reporter']['displayName']
        issue_created = issue_fields['created']
        issue_updated = issue_fields['updated']
        issue_assign = 'Unassigned'
        issue_resolution = 'Unresolved'
        issue_due = 'null'
        issue_serviceteam = 'null'
        issue_createdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(issue_created[:-5], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f').strftime("%m/%d/%y")
        issue_updatedate = datetime.datetime.strptime(issue_updated[:-5], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f').strftime("%m/%d/%y")

        if issue_fields['assignee']:
            issue_assign = issue_fields['assignee']['displayName']
        if issue_fields['resolution']:
            issue_resolution = issue_fields['resolution']['name']
        if issue_fields.get('duedate', None):
            issue_due = issue_fields['duedate']
        if issue_fields.get('customfield_10506', None):
            issue_serviceteam = issue_fields['customfield_10506']['name']
        print(issue_assign)
        print(issue['key'], issue_fields['summary'], issue_reporter, issue_status['name'], issue_resolution, issue_createdate, issue_updatedate, issue_due, issue_serviceteam)
```

Answer (score 0):

Introduce Boolean variable `i` if your issue is with `print(issue_assign)`:

```
def assigne(username):

    responses = fetch(server + Ticket_Week + ' and assignee='+ username)

    duplicate = []
    object = {}
    i = True
    for issue in responses['issues']:
        issue_fields = issue['fields']
        issue_status = issue_fields['status']
        issue_reporter = issue_fields['reporter']['displayName']
        issue_created = issue_fields['created']
        issue_updated = issue_fields['updated']
        issue_assign = 'Unassigned'
        issue_resolution = 'Unresolved'
        issue_due = 'null'
        issue_serviceteam = 'null'
        issue_createdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(issue_created[:-5], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f').strftime("%m/%d/%y")
        issue_updatedate = datetime.datetime.strptime(issue_updated[:-5], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f').strftime("%m/%d/%y")

        if issue_fields['assignee']:
            issue_assign = issue_fields['assignee']['displayName']
        if issue_fields['resolution']:
            issue_resolution = issue_fields['resolution']['name']
        if issue_fields.get('duedate', None):
            issue_due = issue_fields['duedate']
        if issue_fields.get('customfield_10506', None):
            issue_serviceteam = issue_fields['customfield_10506']['name']



        if i:
            print(issue_assign)
            i = False
        print(issue['key'], issue_fields['summary'], issue_reporter, issue_status['name'], issue_resolution, issue_createdate, issue_updatedate, issue_due, issue_serviceteam)
```

**EDIT** (based on comment):

If you have multiple users you have multiple options but I will stress out two:

Lets say that your usernames are 1, 2, 3 and 4:

```
usernames = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for user in usernames:
    assigne(user)
```

Other option is in my opinion a better solution:

```
def assigne(usernames):
    if type(a) is not list:
        a = [a]
    for username in usernames:
        responses = fetch(server + Ticket_Week + ' and assignee='+ username)
        ...
```

This way you can forward your username as a single username or you can call your function with list of usernames.

Comment: Wow Work like a charm. Thanks

Comment: I got another question zipa. How do output of all the users. I got multiple users. Do i create variable to store all the users use the this as function?